# What does this regex pattern match?

Tags: python, regex

```
regex = re.compile(r"\s*[-*+]\s*(.+)")
```

Especially this part: `\s*[-*+]`

I want to match this `string`:

```
[John](person)is good and [Mary](person) is good too.
```

But it fails.

Does the `\s*[-*+]` mean the following:

matches an optional space, followed by one of the characters: `-`, `*`, `+`

This is in Python.

Comment: Go [here](https://regexr.com/4ljra) and put your mouse over each part of the regex for an explanation piece by piece. Add sample text to the box to see how it matches.

Comment: `\s*[-*+]` this means 0 or more white spaces and any character `-` `*` or `+`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. And your input string doesn't have any of those characters.

Comment: What are you attempting to match? I'm guessing you want to pull out the names and tags, such as `John` and `person`?

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb, Yes, it is.

Comment: `\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)` would do the trick, matching `[` followed by any amount of characters followed by `]` or `[` followed by any amount of characters followed by `]`.

Comment: @ling Include actual question in your post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern `\s*[-*+]\s*(.+)` means:

`\s*` - match zero or more whitesapces

`[-*+]` - match one characters from the set: `-` or `*` or `+`

`(.+)` - match one or more of any characters and store it inside capturing group (`.` means any character and brackets denote capturing group)

In your sentence, pattern won't match anything due to lack of any of characters from the set `-*+`.

It would match, for example `* (person) is good too.` in

```
[John](person)is good and [Mary] * (person) is good too.
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z8SSn4/1)

In order to match names and their description in brackets use `\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)`

Explanation:

`\[` - match `[` literally

`([^\]]+)` - match one or more characters other from `]` and store it in first captuirng group

`\]` - match `[` literally

`\(` - match `(` literally

`([^)]+)` - match one or more characters other from `)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z8SSn4/2)